# How a linear datastructure can be used to implement a non linear datastructure

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph

Basically my questions is how list and matrix can be used to represent the graph, as list and matrix is linear data structure and graph is a non-linear data structure

Comment: Usually they are used to represent the edges of the graph as adjacency matrix/list. So all nodes vs all nodes, which gives a square, a 2D matrix. Not necessarily the best representation though, highly depends on the context. I more often went for `Map<Node, Set<Edge>> nodeToOutgoingEdges` and the same for `incomingEdges` in the context I usually worked with graphs.

Comment: You can build more complicated things from simpler things.

Comment: Okay @Zabuzard thanks.

Comment: that's true @PaulHankin :D

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in matrix representation, we only change the value of a particular cell when the vertex represented by column and row number are connected. And list is simply the list for all the neighbors of a particular vertex. In matrix, we store zeroes for pair of vertices not connected and is extra space.

Comment: Oh okay 
thanks this answer was useful
@adityakarad28.

i want explore more on it.